# ASP NET Dropdown box in a user control losing viewstate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a usercontrol in an ASP NET web application on which I create dropdown lists based on some loaded data (from an XML file via a component in the BIN directory)

I found that I couldn't retrieve the values across postbacks, and I've been doing a fair bit of reading to figure out why. What I would like someone to explain is why the following condition exists:

```
Dim dd As New DropDownList
With dd
  .Items.Add(New ListItem("First Item"))
  .Items.Add(New ListItem("Second Item"))
  .Items.Add(sts(0))
  .Items.Add(sts(1))
  .Items.Add(sts(2))
  .Items.Add(New ListItem("Third Item"))
End With
AddHandler dd.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf changed
divControls.Controls.Add(dd)
```

In the code above the three items 'First Item', 'Second Item' and 'Third Item' all behave correctly, as you can see they are added directly to the dropdown box in code. The items sts(0), sts(1) and sts(2) are all loaded from an XML file into either an array or list of string

Interestingly, sts(0) always posts back correctly, but any subsequent items which are added from the dynamic source don't. I've tried a bunch of ways of getting my list of strings into the dropdown so that they are still there upon postback but I'm not having much luck, would be most grateful if anyone could shed some understanding on this

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I need to give each ListItem a value, I had lazily coded just the text portion since I wasn't using ordinals in the list, but ASP NET needed the ordinal value, or the list item value, to register the item for event validation, I expect ASP NET was only able to give subsequent items in the array or list of string the same ordinal or listitem value as all the other members of the collection, since they are from the same object. Works now!